# How to check collision of a specific collider on an object? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Seems like a simple question, but I can't seem to find a solution. I have a 3d cube with two colliders added, a cube collider and a sphere collider. For example, the cube collider is located in the center of the cube and fires when the cube flies through another object. And the sphere is a large collider and it works when the cube flies next to another object.
With the OnTriggerEnter method, I can get information about the collider of the object the cube is interacting with. But how to get information about the colliders of the cube itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnCollisonEnter()` to check if your object has hit another collider.

To specify information about each collider on your object, you should be able to use `GetType()` to determine which collider was hit.

For example:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.collider.GetType() == typeof(BoxCollider)) {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, in this method, as well as in OnTriggerEnter, I can find out about the collider that the 3d cube collided with. I need to know which of the cube's colliders was involved in the collision.

Comment: You could use `gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>()` if the script is attached to your cube object.